# index.html is not recognized in IIS of Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, windows-server

In IIS, I have removed iisstart.htm page in Default Web Site. Then I uploaded a blank index.html page, but it did not work.

When i try to load: "http://localhost" a forbidden error occurs, telling that i cannot browse directory.

When I try to load: "http://localhost/index.html", and 404 error occurs.

Any help, please?

Comment: There's a problem with IIS binding - check if application pool identity having proper permissions to the root folder of the site. Also ensure you've set default document to include "index.html" entry, and check IIS error log for further details.

Comment: Finally, I have opened iisstart.htm and modified it for my needs. I don't know  why index.html did not work, even when it is listed on top of default document list.

Comment: Are you deactivated "Hide file extension for known file types" (ensure the file is not in double extension e.g. `index.html.txt`)? What kind of application pool configuration & site bindings you have then? Perhaps setting "unassigned" bindings for certain occasions work.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you were absolutely right. That was the problem.